# Error message: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am learning new stuff and I am trying to run a spring boot app. When I click on submit request on UI:

```
Error could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
```

in intelliJ, below error is showing

```
authenticated user user, setting security context
2021-04-20 23:52:54.052  WARN 11796 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2021-04-20 23:52:54.052 ERROR 11796 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'request_id' doesn't have a default value
2021-04-20 23:52:54.055 ERROR 11796 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause
```

Comment: Have you read the logging? That tells you exactly what's wrong... **Field 'request_id' doesn't have a default value**.

Answer (score 1):

probably, application is trying to save the field `request_id` without a value.
Provide a default value for this field in database or source code.